# sqlite3 binary - problems with german umlauts/special characters

Tags: android, sqlite, adb

When I connect via adb with my Android device, commands like

```
# echo äöüß
äöüß
```

just work fine. But when I open some database file via sqlite3 for testing purposes to print some results, e.g.

```
# sqlite3 blablabla.db
sqlite> SELECT * FROM bhflist;
```

it prints me something like

```
1|Darmstadt Hbf
2|Mainz Hbf
3|Schlo�, Darmstadt
```

So in this case, the "ß"-sign is not printed correctly.

Any ideas how to achieve proper results? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the encoding used by your terminal?

Comment: UTF-8. “PRAGMA encoding;“ outputs the same. And, as said, “echo äöüß“ works as well.

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT hex(Name) FROM bhflist WHERE id=3`?

Comment: Result:
    sqlite> SELECT hex(data) FROM bhflist WHERE _id=3;
    5363686C6FDF2C204461726D737461647400413D31404F3D5363686C6FDF2C204461726D737461647440583D3836353532353440593D343938373238383140553D3830404C3D30303031313630313640423D3140703D3133393033393138303140A731A738363535323534A73439383732383831

Comment: This is not a valid string. Show the code that inserted this data into the database.

Comment: I don't have this code. I am writing a developer's app to view and edit sqlite db-files and was playing around with some random file. But you're right, I guess, it's not a string but a “blob“ which is stored there. Since a blob can be a lot without “knowing“ it, there is no way in editing it anyway, is there?

Comment: `hex` converts everything into a blob. This data might be a string (check `typeof(data)`), but it's not a valid UTF-8 string.

Comment: sqlite> SELECT typeof(data) FROM bhflist;
blob
blob
blob
blob
blob
So I might maybe at least “show“ the data to the user, but the option of editing it in the app does not make much sense, does it?

Comment: If it's a blob, it probably was never intended to be interpreted as a (UTF-8) string.